# Finding words with dash/hyphen and without in same regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Have the following examples:

Find:       \(([A-Z][A-Za-z-\s]*)\)      --          (Ki-Woo)

Find:       \(([A-Z][A-Za-z\s]*)\)        --              (Drunk)

How do I find both (Ki-Woo) and (Drunk) with same regex ?

Also, how do I find instances where there should be a SPACE's?

<b>MR.SMITH   ------>   <b> MR. SMITH

Should be a space between <b> and MR. and SMITH

Thanks in advance !

EDIT:

`\\([A-Z]*(?:(\h*|-)[A-Z0-9][a-z]*)*\)`

Still not sure how to pass result to Replace: field in NP++ ? ?

The ($1) worked on a similar Find: below for MR. SMITH: but not on the one above with (Ki-Woo);(Drunk);(Woman 1)

Find:       `([A-Z][A-Z\.\s]*\:+)`
Replace:    `\<font color\=\"\#FFA500\"\>\<b\>($1)\<\/b\>\<\/font\>`

Not sure how the ($1) ....   Watching more UTube

Comment: Could you please properly format your question? See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, use:
`\([A-Z)[a-z]*(?:-[A-Z][a-z]*)*\)`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/76wjcG/1)

For the second:

`\h*MR\.\h*[A-Z]+`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/5vjaKe/1)

Comment: Thanks Toto, now I understand how the website regex101 works .. lol  .... both answers are exactly what I was looking for ... 

Comment: `\([A-Z]*(?:(\h*|-)[A-Z0-9][a-z]*)*\)`  ..... `\([A-Z]*(?:(\h*|-)[A-Z0-9][a-z]*)*\)`     Still not sure how to pass result to Replace: field in NP++ ? ?     Watching more UTube  .... this worked on a similar Find: but not on this one.    `Find: MR.  SMITH: ([A-Z][A-Z\.\s]*\:+)    Replace: \<font color\=\"\#FFA500\"\>\<b\>($1)\<\/b\>\<\/font\>

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:

```regex
(\w+-)?[\w-]+
```

The above pattern matches both words with and without dashes, except it also catches the first word followed by a dash, and capture them in a group. Then, you could check whether the first group has any value. If it does, then the word is in the format of `something-something`, otherwise it is without dashes. **Note that this is only works for very basic cases where dashes appear in middle of consecutive letters, and you will need to modify it so that it meets your needs if you want a more specific RegEx pattern.**

For your second question, the following pattern could be a working example.

```regex
[>\.]\w
```

This works for the case you posted because it matches a greater-than sign or a dot followed by any letter.

Again, to have RegEx patterns that meet your specific needs, you need to pinpoint what patterns you would want to search for, and construct RegEx patterns from there.

Comment: Thanks Quach Tri Dat

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your Question ..
But may be this code is what you was looking for..

Find:  `(?<=\()Drunk|ki-Woo(?=\))`
This will detect both `drunk` & `ki-Woo`  surrounded by brackets `()`
but brackets won't be part of it...

Regarding Mr.Smith & Mr. Smith ...
Just add Question mark  after space,
eg.  `Mr. ?Smith` will detect both of them ....

Comment: Drunk|ki-Woo ... should not be part of the FIND: as its what I'm searching ... sorry I was not clearer.  Change this (Drunk) to this Drunk:   The Replace I have works

Answer (score 0):

```
Find:     ([A-Z][A-Z\.\s]*\:+)                  
Replace:  \<font color\=\"\#FFA500\"\>\<b\>($1)\<\/b\>\<\/font\>

From:     MR. SMITH:
To:       <font color="#FF4500"><b>MR. SMITH:</b></font>
```

Not sure why the ($1) works on the above but doesn't work on the below:

```
Find:     \([A-Z)[a-z]*(?:-[A-Z][a-z]*)*\)
Replace:  \<font color\=\"\#FFA500\"\>\<b\>$1\:\<\/b\>\<\/font\>

From:     (Ki-Woo)
To:       <font color="#FF4500"><b>Ki-Woo:</b></font>
```

As you can see I'm still on BABY STEPS .... Ever watch "What About Bob" with Bill Murray ... funniest movie I ever watched. So I'm basically clueless as to how to take results of Find: and pull it into the Replace:

Examples I had to go by:

```
Find:       (?<=\[)([^]]+)      ;[ across two lines ]
Replace:    \U\1                ;Uppercase
Replace:    \L\1                ;Lowercase
```

### Replacing Square Brackets with Round Brackets

```
Find:       \[([^A-Z].+?)\]                 ;[dramatic music]
Replace:    \($1\)                      ;(dramatic music)
```

Comment: Also really confused how this forum works too .... 67 year ole noob ... ROTFLMAO